# How to lock few rows when udating with begin tran

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

### see my code

```
BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE EMP2 WITH (HOLDLOCK,ROWLOCK)
    SET SALARY=100 WHERE ID IN (1,2)

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00';

    PRINT 'Job complete'

COMMIT TRAN
```

i use wait for to simulate some dealy.

when i execute the above code and from other query window when i issue select like `select * from Emp2` then i saw data was not coming. it means update statement place a lock on table not few rows.

but i want those rows should be coming which are excluded in update statement.
update statement updating only employee whose id are 1 and 2 so i want other employee data should come when begin tran is running.

please tell me how could i achieve it. thanks

Comment: It looks like you are after the `READPAST` query hint.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov ?? that causes behavior changes by randomly omitting rows.

Comment: `READPAST` doesn't not **randomly** omit rows, it omits rows locked by other transactions. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: This usually amounts to random behavior because it's almost always unpredictable what exact rows are locked. It's extremely hard to globally control the entire worklock. READPAST generally is for queues and reports and such. In any case the OP likely can't tolerate this since almost no query can tolerate this.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your code locks only two rows, the `select * from Emp2` statement requires the whole data-set to be retrieved. To prevent `DIRTY READS` it will wait for the `UPDATE` to finish. Therefore, to you it looks like the whole table is locked.

To see if it is locking the whole table or just the two rows, you can try running this query (which doesn't include the rows being updated), while waiting for the `UPDATE` to finish:

`select * from Emp2 where ID = 3 -- or any other ID in your table`

Try this one to:

`set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select * from Emp2`. This should return the whole table, but rows being updated may not show the correct result.

Comment: I just tried that, and I can select any row(s) that is(are) not being updated (while the update query is running).

Comment: Yes, but there's a catch: you don't know which rows have been skipped (`select * from table` retrieves different results depending on whether any rows are blocked or not). If you don't use `readpast` you can access rows that are not blocked, while you have to wait for those that are blocked.